# JasperReport does not show table

Tags: jasper-reports

I'am using Jasper studio to generate pdf template. I added a table in this template without sources or database conenction but in jasper does not show the table. Below is my jrxml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.11.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.11.0-0c4056ccaa4d25a5a8c45672d2f764ea3498bebb  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="06cb70de-815a-4623-b868-91a92feca771">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#549BDE">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="d011bfa0-d2bd-475d-b7d1-4d69deec36be">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="Dataset2" uuid="563537d5-3b04-4cb9-93d6-4eb48c6fb5c7">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="Dataset3" uuid="fa68464d-99c7-4751-8e25-f173ce78f908">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="tableActiviteValide" uuid="bc90850c-a424-455b-8cb5-dd5df5282de5">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="codeTournee" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dateTournee" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="heureDepartTournee" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="heureDuPremierPoint" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="nbPointsPrevu" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="nomChauffeur" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="respectETA" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="statutTournee" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="51" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="120" y="-16" width="320" height="66" uuid="240b4bfe-6b32-4a96-8bf1-69ba08f35e74"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contôle retour collecte
Impression de la synthèse de l'activité]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-16" y="10" width="237" height="40" uuid="9aa786c1-e331-4790-99cc-d509a0f8626c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.String("Impression de ") + java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY").format(java.time.LocalDate.now()) + new java.lang.String(" à ") + java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").format(java.time.LocalTime.now())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="220" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="10" y="20" width="535" height="190" uuid="58a48853-5a63-485a-8dd5-a4e3a36076c8"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="48" width="60" height="20" uuid="ac6227f3-aa2c-4355-93c2-a3a67aacd2b1"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tournée:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="169" y="48" width="60" height="20" uuid="3e0708e0-cc0f-4282-9e60-fa962be46bc9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{codeTournee}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="80" width="60" height="20" uuid="a794c118-84d7-4f73-a87c-42366cc1d5fa"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="110" width="120" height="20" uuid="fdfc42f2-30ca-4302-bb43-2e0b453cedf6"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Heure de départ:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="140" width="136" height="20" uuid="f7abe915-02c3-4b85-839a-b528e4d7692b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Heure du 1er point:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="170" width="136" height="20" uuid="331e25b0-d0ef-461b-974b-f8a676b42505"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nb points prévus:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="169" y="80" width="60" height="20" uuid="d75802b2-b117-4b79-9929-fe76fa8a594b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{dateTournee}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="169" y="110" width="60" height="20" uuid="1264ce76-8691-4b1e-9fad-0bb2ec2b5780">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{heureDepartTournee}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="169" y="140" width="60" height="20" uuid="501a135a-f70c-4572-b9a1-becaada10c91">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{heureDuPremierPoint}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="169" y="170" width="60" height="20" uuid="6be68507-0e04-439a-a94e-3fb29c6b046f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{nbPointsPrevu}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="48" width="60" height="20" uuid="d2e71c08-f045-4d9a-a478-eb2814ae58ab"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nom:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="400" y="48" width="60" height="20" uuid="e8878870-3bcc-4237-8ba7-fb1eecd96482">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{nomChauffeur}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="140" width="90" height="20" uuid="91532fe1-2320-4f0f-ab7d-c69d98198911"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[RespectETA:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="170" width="90" height="20" uuid="3e2d848e-9be5-47fb-aa9a-47c7634869fa"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Statut Tournée:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="400" y="140" width="60" height="20" uuid="92b863f7-011e-4a25-8e23-0d89066db13a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{respectETA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="400" y="170" width="60" height="20" uuid="9091a71f-fa56-413a-b0ed-31d57c34f1e9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{respectETA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="353" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="4" width="534" height="66" uuid="8d8baf3e-51bf-436a-9691-dfda004dce54"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Attention, les informations données à titre d'information pour permettre de mieux gérer l'activité sont susceptibles d'être modifiées à la suite du contrôle back-office, l'agence reste à votre disposition.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="20" y="80" width="311" height="85" uuid="52b7823f-9442-433e-b665-1398b400ae88">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableActiviteValide" uuid="5ac2165e-840c-4a99-9511-4bd1a604f544">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="ee0f7403-3157-4b14-aeaa-c8fb9dc5a97b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne1"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="60" rowSpan="2"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30"/>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="a9e963ba-1a80-4a5d-85b8-1d0d14e0ff05">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne2"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="60" rowSpan="2"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30"/>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="78afc7bc-a1f8-4fa8-aeac-311be51643c4">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne3"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="60" rowSpan="2"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30"/>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:columnGroup width="80" uuid="7c6c7ce4-2a9a-4735-b4ce-55e99ff0379f">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonnes [2]"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:column width="40" uuid="8033f192-d8fb-46f2-a87f-5acba54f6138">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne4"/>
                            <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                            <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                            <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                            <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30"/>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="40" uuid="5f31f40c-f884-4ec1-a2f7-4cda37699e00">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne5"/>
                            <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                            <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                            <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                            <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30"/>
                        </jr:column>
                    </jr:columnGroup>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="723c94fd-6ccc-4f10-b827-18477cc941fb">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne6"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="60" rowSpan="2"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30"/>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="4aea6eaf-a426-4be7-829a-a9b94c1b5777">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne7"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="60" rowSpan="2"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30"/>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

There is no problem that had been shown in my report and the table is not visible in my template. How Can i resolve this?
Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give some data to the table, otherwise jasper don't show it because nothing is to show when you give no data.

Comment: How about a reaktion to my answer? @bdelmouheimen